# Save Updated Order Of CollectionView Images To UserDefaults - Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, nsuserdefaults

I have a collectionview which loads images and displays them. I have implemented gestures so that a person can hold and reorder the images, however the order does not save. Is there a way to save this order through User Defaults? If so, where would I implement this to save the order and load again? Below is my code for collectionView. Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated!

```
    func collectionView(_ imageCollection: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.posts.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ imageCollection: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = imageCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
        let post = self.posts[indexPath.item]
        cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: post.imageURL))
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ imageCollection: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch mMode {
        case .view:
            imageCollection.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        case .select:
            dictionarySelectedIndexPath[indexPath] = true
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ imageCollection: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if mMode == .select {
            dictionarySelectedIndexPath[indexPath] = false
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let item = posts.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        posts.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on your example code, I think it looks fine just missing to reload. :)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
            let item = posts.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
            posts.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
            collectionView.reloadData() //the missing code
}
```